# async function with await fetch inside do-while loop

Tags: javascript, async-await, do-while

I have a problem with the function below. I can see the log messages as follows:

> in fetchData
>   before while
>   in while
>   After this, nothing happens until I get a timeout:
>   VM344:1 GET http://192.168.1.91:27080/sds/deception/_find?batch_size=100&criteria={%20%22$and%22%20:%20[{%20%22$or%22%20:%20[{%20%22reason%22%20:%202%20},%20{%20%22reason%22%20:%203%20}]%20},%20{%20%22ts%22:%20{%20%22$gt%22%20:%20{%20%22$date%22%20:%201549903417360}}}]}
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
>   TypeError: Failed to fetch "Failed to fetch"
>   after while

Appreciate some hints to what I do wrong.

```
async function fetchData() {
    console.log("in fetchData");
    let page = 0;
    var result = [];
    var mylen;

    var hourAgo = Date.now(Date.now());           // datetime now
    hourAgo = hourAgo - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;   // subtract 30 days
    var myobj = {};
    myobj.ts = String(hourAgo);                     // make unix epoch in ms

    url = `http://192.168.1.91:27080/sds/deception/_find?batch_size=100&criteria={ "$and" : [{ "$or" : [{ "reason" : 2 }, { "reason" : 3 }] }, { "ts": { "$gt" : { "$date" : ${myobj.ts}}}}]}`;
    console.log("before while");
    do {
        console.log("in while");

        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const res_json = await response.json();
            result = result.concat(res_json.results);
            mylen = res_json.results.length;
            if (page++ == 0) {
                url = `http://192.168.1.91:27080/sds/deception/_more?id=${res_json.id}&batch_size=100`;
                console.log(url);
            }
            console.log("Id: ", res_json.id, "\tLen: ", res_json.results.length);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err, err.message);
        }
    } while (mylen > 0);

    console.log("after while");

    //console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So the `do/while` and `async/await` code works fine. Do you get a timeout as well when directly visiting that url?

Comment: No. If I just do a curl it works.

Comment: Does CURL send exactly the same headers as your javascript? Use the browser devtools (network monitor) to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one - serialize your JSON

I observe that your URL is not encoded (URLEncoded)

```js
fetchData()
async function fetchData() {
  console.log("in fetchData");
  let page = 0;
  var result = [];
  var mylen;

  var hourAgo = Date.now(Date.now()); // datetime now
  hourAgo = hourAgo - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; // subtract 30 days
  var myobj = {};
  myobj.ts = String(hourAgo); // make unix epoch in ms

  url = `http://192.168.1.91:27080/sds/deception/_find?batch_size=100&criteria={ "$and" : [{ "$or" : [{ "reason" : 2 }, { "reason" : 3 }] }, { "ts": { "$gt" : { "$date" : ${myobj.ts}}}}]}`;
  console.log("before while");
  do {
    console.log("in while");

    try {
      console.log("URL being fetched - NOT ENCODED", url)
      let encodedURL = encodeURI(url);
      console.log("URL after ENCODING", encodedURL)
      const response = await fetch(encodedURL);
      const res_json = await response.json();
      result = result.concat(res_json.results);
      mylen = res_json.results.length;
      if (page++ == 0) {
        url = `http://192.168.1.91:27080/sds/deception/_more?id=${res_json.id}&batch_size=100`;
        console.log(url);
      }
      console.log("Id: ", res_json.id, "\tLen: ", res_json.results.length);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err, err.message);
    }
  } while (mylen > 0);

  console.log("after while");

  //console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

This will help you on URLEncoding

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuri

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: I tried with both encodeURIComponent and also JSON.stringify as suggested. Same behavior.

Comment: I see that your result is different from mine. http://192.168.1.91:27080/sds/deception/_find?batch_size=100&criteria=%7B%20%22%24and%22%20%3A%20%5B%7B%20%22%24or%22%20%3A%20%5B%7B%20%22reason%22%20%3A%202%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20%22reason%22%20%3A%203%20%7D%5D%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20%22ts%22%3A%20%7B%20%22%24gt%22%20%3A%20%7B%20%22%24date%22%20%3A%201549924926590%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D

Comment: URL after ENCODING is correct way to pass JSON to your service - make sure u are able to access your service from postman and the likes with the URL which I have printed and then verify

Comment: Thanks all. In the end I found I **also** had a network issue in addition to the encloding. Solved now.